# Combining txt and csv files in a ton of folders into one big csv file

Tags: linux, wordpress, csv, content-management-system, cat

How would you go in Linux about combing *all* files of this archive: https://github.com/tpb-archive/4xxxxxx/ into one or several big csv files?

Or the better question: How would you go about putting this whole archive into a WordPress blog? With "comments.csv", "description.txt", "details.csv" and "filelist.csv" as content of one post.
I've been using [WP ALL Import](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-all-import/) for other projects.

Or what other CMS would you use to generate html files from those 4 files?

Comment: Take a look at [how do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Try to give enough details to see what you tried, what you want and what are you looking for. So far it is a bit unclear.

Comment: Hm, sorry.. I haven't tried anything yet, only googled for solutions.. I want to combine comments.csv, description.txt, details.csv and filelist.csv into one csv file with one row. Then I want to combine that new csv file with all the others in the other folders, one row for each.. ;X So a csv Importer for Wordpress can put the 4 files of on folder into one post..

Comment: Again: try to describe things in the question itself (not in the comments), so that it is clear what you want. Try to read the link I provided above and show your attempts. Otherwise, it is quite unlikely that people will be able to find a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try: `find /path/to/directory/*.* | xargs cat >> ~/concatenatedFile.txt`